# Is there any free Python to C translator?

Tags: python, c, code-translation

Is there any free Python to C translator? for example capable to translate such lib as [lib for Fast content-aware image resizing](http://blog.eikke.com/index.php/ikke/2007/09/02/seam_carving_content_aware_image_resizin) (which already depends on some C libs) to C files?

Comment: @Mike: It is perfectly possible to program in a OOP fashion in C. So that is not really relevant.

Comment: @kigurai, It was relevant in the original edit because it was phrased like "classes" was a language feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that cython is what you're looking for http://www.cython.org/

Answer (score 7):

[Shedskin translates Python code to C++](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/).

Answer (score 2):

The fantastic **[PyPy](http://pypy.org)** project which aims to: **"translate a Python-level description of the Python language itself to lower level languages"**, has a **[C backend](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/translation.html#c-backend)**. That is one of the lower level languages it aims to translate programs to is C.