# n-gram counting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, nlp, n-gram

I am building a MySQL database that will have roughly 10,000 records.  Each record will contain a textual document (a few pages of text in most cases).  I want to do all sorts of n-gram counting across the entire database.  I have algorithms already written in Python that will what I want against a directory containing a large number of text files, but  to do that I will need to extract 10,000 text files from the database - this will have performance issues.

I'm a rookie with MySQL, so I'm not sure if it has any built-in features that do n-gram analysis, or whether there are good plugins out there that would do it.  Please note that I need to go up to at least 4-grams (preferably 5-grams) in my analysis, so the simple 2-gram plugins I've seen won't work here.  I also need to have the ability to remove the stopwords from the textual documents before doing the n-gram counting.

Any ideas from the community?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: Aren't you doing this n-gram processing offline when nobody is waiting for an answer? Or do you need to generate a new n-gram database quickly, across many text files, every time a batch of files is added?

Comment: I'm aware of questions similar to this being asked in other forums. What tends to happen is the questioner fiddles about in SQL for a few days before giving up and wandering off to find some application level solution (e.g. PHP) for performing the string analysis. Just sayin'

Comment: You cannot do reasonable 5-gram processing in an RDBMS. Storarge is feasible, bu very painfull if you are lacking the ability of recursive queries. (mysql is a bad choice in this respect) My own toy project http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ has all the raw text rows (about 2M currently) present in a (postgres) database, but does all of it's 5-gram Markov processing in a standalone C-program, storing it's trees (35M nodes) in a flatfile. IMHO Python is too slow for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a dedicated full-text search index program like lucene/solr, which has much richer and extensible support for this sort of thing.  It will require you to learn a bit to get it set up, but it sounds as if you want to mess around at a level that will be difficult to customize in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to prematurely optimize ;) you could [translate your python into C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650280/623735) and then wrap it with thin [mysql UDF wrapper code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-compiling.html).

But I'd highly recommend just loading your documents one at a time and running your python scripts on them to populate a mysql table of n-grams. My hammer for every nail at the moment is [Django](http://djangoproject.com). It's [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/optimization/) makes interacting with mysql tables and optimizing those interactions a cinch. I'm using it to do statistics in python on multimillion record databases for [production sites](http://bpd.lbl.gov) that have to return gobs of data in less than a second.  And any python ORM will make it easier to switch out your database if you find something better than mysql, like postgre. The best part is that there are lots of python and django tools to monitor all aspects of your app's performance (python execution, mysql load/save, memory/swap). That way you can attack the right problem. It may be that sequential bulk mysql reads aren't what's slowing you down...