# Executing a python script line-by-line using the C++ Python API

Tags: c++, python, api, interpreter

My goal is ultimately to execute a python script that manipulates values in my C++ program, one line at a time, returning execution to my C++ program between statements in the python script. Right now, I'm been attempting to feed the python interpreter my script one line at a time. But it wants a context, and I have no idea how to construct that. Can anyone point me to some good tutorials (the documentation is not very good for this).

I chose the answer that most closely answered my question, but I believe this may not be enough control for some applications.
An answer that works for those applications might involve lower-level calls in the Python API. Please answer the question if you have an answer that grants more control over execution.

I Asked another question following this one, because I encountered different problems afterwards which are very closely related. Link: [Python C API - Stopping Execution (and continuing it later)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7809321/996118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will be difficult to feed a script one line at a time.  Look into `sys.settrace()` to set a function that is invoked at each line of execution.  You can also set it in the C API using `PyEval_SetTrace`, in a slightly different form.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll look at it. Didn't know what a trace was. Thanks.

Comment: AWSOME. Thanks so much! Question adequately answered.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that I fully understand your goal, but some 8 months ago I wanted to do something similar.  I wanted to be able to drive my c++ application from python scripts.  I was on win32, Qt, gcc.  It turns out that these days gdb, the debugger for gcc, can be scripted via python.  It took me a lot of reading and few days of work, but it worked well.  I did not have to add any extra code into my c++ sources!

Comment: Can GDB accept scripts at runtime and be included in a release build?

Comment: guy above had solution: python API had a solution I was blind to because of inexperience in programming: didn't know what a debug trace was. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In my post I should have emphasized that my suggestion, while very cost-effective, will always suffer from serious drawbacks - like the need to compile/link with debug symbols.  In my case it did not matter, in many real-worlds cases it WOULD matter.  Beyond that I can only add that python documentation discusses interfacing python and c/c++ in both directions, I vaguely remember a chapter "Embedding Python Interpreter".  Too rusty, sorry, Ned above probably pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

well i tell you what.. i think the best thing to do is to convert your python script to c++ app. this how you'll have working and useful code to embed in your source.
if your c app is not that big, maybe you prefer to make a c-extension for python and turn the python code to the main app..
either way, i would do it in Cython. 
you can use the following question to understand how to do this job if you'd like: [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code)

Comment: I don't want to simply port my Python code. I'm trying to make it so I can write scripts that are read by my program in real time, in the fashion described in my initial post.