# how to convert python code to cpp

Tags: c++, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code)

I can code in python but have difficulty in writing c++ code, but I have to submit the c++ code, one of my senior suggested me to write the code in python and then write the python code to convert it into c++, I Google it out but cannot find a good guide, Can anybody help me? Your help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean - writing a converter? Learning C++ will take less time I suppose.

Comment: @ Karthik - Thankyou for immidiate reply, I am not switching to c++ because of the speed, so I am least bother about speed, I just want the code in c++. And looked foe cython but my system is not supporting cython.

Comment: @Swapnil -  I want to know if any online source is available to convert python to c++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend writing it in Python and then converting to C++. Not only is it double the effort, but the style of Python code is different from C++ code, mainly because Python is dynamically typed and C++ is statically typed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for you but I can only reinforce what others have posted: don't!
Even if such a solution exists, the code would very likely be quite bad and inefficient (i.e. because the c++ would have to emulate the dynamic nature of python).
Whoever required you to submit c++ code probably had a reason and he will either realize you "cheated" or think you're a very bad programmer. Is this acceptable?

Comment: I agree with you, I am working in a project, my partners in project are good at C/C++, but I am not, I told them,And they have never used python, so the final output of the project should be in C++, we all have agreed to this, I discussed this with my project head and he suggested me to try getting python to C convector. So everybody in my project have an idea what I am planning to do.