# What's the best way to read in, operate line-by-line, and write out in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I have two text files `in.txt` and `out.txt`.

`in.txt`:

```
abc      one    2    3    4
         two    3    4    two    twenty
         three  3    20   8
adbc     two    4    28   3      thirty
```

How can I read line-by-line and operate when necessary?  So that on any line I can check if it has some text in the first column ("abc" and "adbc" in this example), what's in the second column, third column, etc. until that line ends?  Then, based on those operations write into `out.txt`?

For example, if any line has its 6th column (if it has a 6th column) and it says "twenty" then print to `out.txt` "Hello."

or

If the second column is "three" add the following three numbers...

Comment: Is "first column" sometimes empty? Do you know the column widths in advance? Or is white space your delimiter? It changes how you read things.

Comment: Do you have to use C?  Text handling is easier in almost any other language.

Comment: Yes, the first column is sometimes empty and the column widths are not known in advance.  Unfortunately, I have to use C.

Comment: So how do you know whether a token is in first or second column?

Comment: Similarly, (if the column widths are not known in advance and columns can be empty), ***how do you know*** whether “17        42” is columns three and four, very far apart (with column five empty), or columns three and five, with column four empty?

Comment: What if we suppose that columns one and six are optional, yet all others are required?  And there is a tab between columns.

Comment: If the C requirement does not come from a homework assignment, you may be interested in that question: [Convert Python program to C/C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/45249) (spoiler: the accepted answer is [Cython](http://cython.org/))

Comment: If that is homework, please say so. Also get your requirements right; how are columns separated, space, tabs, both? And how is an empty column recognized? E.g. does every space-space or tab-tab means that there is an empty column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about BEST way but here's one way:

Read the file in and use strtok to parse it split up by delimiters. (Then you can use strtok again to read it split up by whitespace)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: See comments above... Strtok was my first thought but it doesn't work with empty columns...

Answer (score 0):

I think strtok can still get the job done. Just follow two different paths based on lines beginning with spaces.

pseudo code:

```
while (line = readline()) {
    if (line[0] == ' ') { // you can check for multiple spaces if necessary.
        // If line begins with empty first column
        tokenize_handle_normal(line);
    } else {
        // If line begins with string in the first column
        tokenize_handle_special(line); // Call tokenize_handle_normal(line) after parsing the first column
    }
}
```