# converting python code to c++

Tags: c++, python

I have a python code that uses various libraries like numpy, scipy etc.. Now due to some reasons, in my program I can use only c/c++. How can I convert this python code to c/c++? I thought of converting everything manually, but I don't know what I should do about the libraries that are being implemented.

Please help.

Comment: Can you "freeze" your Python?  https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

Comment: There is no sensible way of "translating" your Python application which is a **High Level Language** along with any dependent 3rd-party libraries into C++ which is a **Lower Level Language**.

Comment: You'll have to translate them manually,  and try searching for similar libraries.

Comment: `Now due to some reasons` .. may be if you amplify on the reasons, possible solutions may be sought out?

Comment: something like this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html

Comment: Abhijit: I'm trying to develop an android application that uses both python and c++ codes. I couldn't use both sl4a and android-ndk keeping performance and speed in mind. So, I thought of converting everything into c++ and use android-ndk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some of your choices are:

1. Do it by hand and convert to other libraries - long job with lots of potential problems.
2. [Embed python](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) in a C++ shell but leave a lot of it python.
3. Use [nuitka](http://nuitka.net/) to convert and compile - *you should still leave your code as python for maintenance in this case*.
4. Use [cython](http://cython.org/).
5. Use [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe) to convert your python into an exe if you are on windows.
6. Treat your python code as a prototype and start from scratch.