# convert python to c++

Tags: c++

I want to translate the following python code in c ++
Can someone help me ??

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("hello")

fichier = open ('S19.txt','r')
CS_MEF = open ('S19_MEF.txt','w')
ligne = fichier.readline()

i=0
for ligne in fichier:
    id_can = ligne[32]+ligne[33]+ligne[34]+ligne[35]
    if ((id_can == '01A7') or (id_can == '01A8')):

        x = int("0x"+ligne[44]+ligne[45]+ligne[41]+ligne[42],16)
        if x > 0x7FFF:
            x -= 0x10000        
        x = float(x)/17.5
        xd = float(x)*57.29578

        y = int("0x"+ligne[50]+ligne[51]+ligne[47]+ligne[48],16)
        if y > 0x7FFF:
            y -= 0x10000          
        y = float(y)/17.5
        yd = float(y)*57.29578

        z = int("0x"+ligne[56]+ligne[57]+ligne[53]+ligne[54],16)
        if z > 0x7FFF:
            z -= 0x10000          
        z = float(y)/17.5
        zd = float(z)*57.29578

        #print ("0x"+ligne[50]+ligne[51]+ligne[47]+ligne[48])
        chaine = " id ="+ id_can + " x= "+ str(x) + " xd= "+ str(xd) + " y= "+ str(y) + " yd= "+ str(yd) + " z= "+ str(z) + " zd= "+ str(zd) + "\n"
        print (chaine)
        #print ("central tête")
        print(i)
        i = i + 1

        CS_MEF.write( str(i))
        CS_MEF.write(chaine)



print (i)
fichier.close()
CS_MEF.close()
```

Comment: There are various ways to interface Python with C++, including SWIG, Boost Python, and Cython. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to automatically convert Python to C++. Also, Pypy may be worth taking a look at.

Comment: This isn't a great fit for stackoverflow, as you're just asking people to port code to a different language, and people don't tend to like being a code-generation tool. If you have a more specific problem while you're porting it, sure, but not one big code dump.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cython](http://cython.org). The generated code will still depend on Python libraries though. If your goal is to make the code faster by compiling it Cython will help you accomplish this.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why this was downvoted.

Comment: Sorry for necro, but 1st page of Google. I think it's OP sulky about no one doing the hard work for him.