# Binding C libraries on Python and Perl but reverse

Tags: python, c, converters

You know, we can bind every C library on Python or Perl programming languages. A good instance is `PyQt`; `PyQt` is bound from `Qt`.

**My question is:** Can I do the reverse of the above? I mean: suppose I have a library in Python or Perl, and I want to convert it to a C library...can it be done?
However, you can think to convert a web program to shared library or a set of functions.

*My Goal:*  I want to improve a set of security features.

Comment: My question to you is, why do you want to go through all the work of translating the program to modify it? Why not just modify these security features in the original language?

Comment: I'm thinking to a master of sience project to eliminate web server, of course it's an idea....

Comment: So people write their code in python/perl/php, and send it to your 'server' and you run it in C? something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The term of art is "embedding," as in "embedded Python" or "embed a Python interpreter."  Python has a document about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html - the general idea is you must use (at least a small part of) the Python C API to launch Python within a C or C++ application.

Once you realize you can embed a scripting language in C, and that scripting languages can invoke C, you then realize you can also embed one scripting language in another, using C as the bridge between them.  For example, RubyLuaBridge: https://bitbucket.org/neomantra/rubyluabridge

A lot of commercial applications embed a scripting language interpreter within a C or C++ host program.  A good, well-documented example is Adobe Lightroom, which is roughly half C++ and half Lua.  You can read about that from the horse's mouth starting on page xi here: http://www.lua.org/gems/front.pdf

Comment: My understanding is that Lua and Tcl/Tk were originally intended for use embedded in programs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for python at least: [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code).

And for Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlcompile.html.

[EDIT] Per the comment, I'll expand. First, the question "Can I translate Python to C?" has already been answered on SO. See the link.

Second, Perl is actually an interpreted language (just like Python), and has the capability to take that intermediate code and translate it into full blown C for native executables. This is done using the 'B' module and it's other companion modules, such as B::C. There's also a standalone program, 'perlcc' for doing just this. [/EDIT]

Comment: Do you know about PHP?

Comment: True, I was just being lazy. Although, in the case of both the PHP and Python links, they are to other questions asked on stackoverflow, which generally aren't re-answered, hence the links.