# How to get the OpenCV image from Python and use it in C++ in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pybind11

I'm trying to figure out how it is possible to receive an OpenCV image from a Python in C++. I'm trying to send a callback function, from C++ to my Python module, and then when I call a specific python method in my C++ app, I can access the needed image.

Before I add more details, I need to add that there are already several questions in this regard including :

1. [how-to-convert-opencv-image-data-from-python-to-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059843/how-to-convert-opencv-image-data-from-python-to-c/51060110)
2. [pass-image-data-from-python-to-cvmat-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834420/pass-image-data-from-python-to-cvmat-in-c)
3. [writing-python-bindings-for-c-code-that-use-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957492/writing-python-bindings-for-c-code-that-use-opencv)
4. [c-conversion-from-numpy-array-to-mat-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758662/c-conversion-from-numpy-array-to-mat-opencv)

but none of them have anything about `Pybind11`. In fact they are all using the `PyObject` (from `Python.h` header) with and without `Boost.Python`. So my first attempt is to know how it is possible in `Pybind11` knowing that it has support for `Numpy` arrays, so it can hopefully make things much easier.

Also  On the `C++` side, `OpenCV` has two versions, 3.x and 4.x which 4.x as I've recently found, is `C++11` compliant. on Python side, I used OpenCV `3.x` and I'm on a crossroad of which one to choose
and what implications it has when it comes to `Pybind11`.

What I have tried so far: I made a quick dummy callback and tried passing a simple `cv::Mat&` like this :

```cpp
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
...

void cpp_callback1(bool i, std::string id, cv::Mat img)
{ 
    auto timenow = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
    cout  <<"arg1: " << i << " arg2: " << id<<" arg3: " << typeid(img).name() <<" " << ctime(&timenow)<<endl;
}
```

and used it like this :

```cpp
py::list callback_lst;
callback_lst.attr("append")(py::cpp_function(cpp_callback1));

py::dict core_kwargs = py::dict("callback_list"_a = callback_lst,
                                "debug_show_feed"_a = true);

py::object core_obj = core_cls(**core_kwargs);
core_obj.attr("start")();
```

but it fails with an exception on python part which says :

```py
29/03/2020 21:56:47 : exception occured ("(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:\n    1. (arg0: bool, arg1: str, arg2: cv::Mat) -> None\n\nInvoked with: True, '5', array([[[195, 217, 237],\n        [195, 217, 237],\n        [196, 218, 238],\n        ...,\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255]],\n\n       [[195, 217, 237],\n        [195, 217, 237],\n        [195, 217, 237],\n        ...,\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255]],\n\n       [[195, 217, 237],\n        [195, 217, 237],\n        [195, 217, 237],\n        ...,\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255],\n        [211, 241, 255]],\n\n       ...,\n\n       [[120, 129, 140],\n        [110, 120, 130],\n        [113, 122, 133],\n        ...,\n        [196, 209, 245],\n        [195, 207, 244],\n        [195, 207, 244]],\n\n       [[120, 133, 142],\n        [109, 121, 130],\n        [114, 120, 131],\n        ...,\n        [195, 208, 242],\n        [195, 208, 242],\n        [195, 208, 242]],\n\n       [[121, 134, 143],\n        [106, 119, 128],\n        [109, 114, 126],\n        ...,\n        [194, 207, 241],\n        [195, 208, 242],\n        [195, 208, 242]]], dtype=uint8)",) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\F\utils.py", line 257, in start
    self._main_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\F\utils.py", line 301, in _main_loop
    self._execute_callbacks(is_valid, name, frame)
  File "C:\Users\Master\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\F\utils.py", line 142, in _execute_callbacks
    callback(*args)
TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool, arg1: str, arg2: cv::Mat) -> None

Invoked with: True, '5', array([[[195, 217, 237],
        [195, 217, 237],
        [196, 218, 238],
        ...,
        [211, 241, 255],
        [211, 241, 255],
        [211, 241, 255]],

       [[195, 217, 237],
        [195, 217, 237],
        [195, 217, 237],
        ...,
```

Using `py::object` or `py::array_t<uint8_t>` instead of `cv::Mat` doesn't cause any errors, but I can't seem to find a way to cast them back to a `cv::Mat` properly!

I tried to cast the numpy array into a `cv::Mat` as instructed in the comments but the output is garbage:

```cpp
void cpp_callback1(bool i, std::string id, py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{ 
    auto im = img.unchecked<3>();
    auto rows = img.shape(0);
    auto cols = img.shape(1);
    auto type = CV_8UC3;

    //py::buffer_info buf = img.request();
    cv::Mat img2(rows, cols, type, img.ptr());
    cv::imshow("test", img2);
}
```

results in :

[image]

It seems to me, the strides, or something in that direction is messed up that image is showing like this. what am I doing wrong here? I couldn't use the img.strides() though! when printed it using py::print, it shows `960` or something like that. So I'm completely clueless how to interpret that!

Comment: Have the callback take a numpy array instead of `Mat`. Then in the callback, create a `Mat` header for the numpy array's data buffer. (keep in mind that this shares the bufffer, so if you need the `Mat` to have longer lifetime than the callback's scope, you'll have to make a deep copy)

Comment: @DanMašek , thanks a lot, but that do you mean `py::array_t<double>` ?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. Although you probably have to change the template parameter to match the actual datatype of the numpy array -- if it's an image, it's probably `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks a lot. I can really appreciate a snippet of some kind. I'm kind of lost here! specially concerning the Mat header! how should I do this?

Comment: [This](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) constructor (or one of the related ones). You have to extract the width and height and also channel count from the numpy array's `shape`, and get a pointer to its data buffer. -- looks like the [direct access](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#direct-access) functionality in pybind let's you do that.

Comment: I'd love to give you a complete code example, but I'd first have to set up PyBind and grok some of the details. Wouldn't mind getting bit more familiar with it, so that's not an issue, but at this particular moment, I've still got some work I need to do tonight... maybe later tonight.

Comment: @DanMašek , Thanks a lot man. its really greatly appreciated. I'll get to it and hopefully get it solved. in case I faced something I'll update the question.

Comment: @DanMašek : I did this, but the resulting image is corrupted. could you please have a look and see if you can spot where I went wrong? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72774044/11261546) might be very useful and offers a way of doing this without hardcoding the type of the array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ultimately could successfully get this to work thanks to @[DanMasek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) and this [link](https://www.twblogs.net/a/5d400d6cbd9eee517422e088/zh-cn):

```
void cpp_callback1(py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{ 
    py::buffer_info buf = img.request();
    cv::Mat mat(buf.shape[0], buf.shape[1], CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)buf.ptr);
    
    cv::imshow("test", mat);
}
```

note that the cast is necessary, or otherwise, you'd get a blackish screen only!
However, if somehow there was a way like `py::return_value_policy` that we could use  to change the type of reference, so even though the python part ends, the c++ side wouldn't crash would be great.

side note :
it seems the `ptr` property exposed in the `numpy` array, is actually not a `py::handle` but a `PyObject*&`. I couldn't have a successful conversion and thus resorted to the solution I posted above. I'll update this answer, when I figure this out.

### Update:

I found out, the arrays `data` holds a pointer to the underlying buffer and can be used easily as well.
From `<pybind11/numpy.h>` L681:

```
/// Pointer to the contained data. If index is not provided, points to the
/// beginning of the buffer. May throw if the index would lead to out of bounds access.
```

So my original code that used `img.ptr()`, can work using `img.data()` like this :

```cpp
void cpp_callback1(py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{ 
    //auto im = img.unchecked<3>();
    auto rows = img.shape(0);
    auto cols = img.shape(1);
    auto type = CV_8UC3;

    cv::Mat img2(rows, cols, type, (unsigned char*)img.data());
    cv::imshow("test", img2);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. BTW, that line with `img2` seems redungdant here. | I got to the point of calling a pybind wrapped function in embedded Python. It's 3am not tho, so i'll resume tomorrow. Good insights here!

Comment: Thanks a lot. its really appreciated :)

Comment: Good observation with `data` rather than `ptr`. However, keep in mind that right now you're using a C-style cast to cast away const from the data pointer. You could use `mutable_data` which returns a non-const pointer, and you don't need any cast at all in that case. | Here is a draft of a fairly generic conversion function: https://pastebin.com/sawt2EFt It still needs some more testing and bullet-proofing tho.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look at it. really appreciate you kind help and time on this :)

Comment: @DanMašek Do you happen to know how we can expose `py::object` in C ? 
consider this function that we have above, it accepts a `py::array_t`, but if I want to expose this in C, it seems void* doesnt work (on python part it raises the exception). 
How should we go about this?

Answer (score 5):

To convert between `cv::Mat` and `np.ndarray`, you can use [pybind11_opencv_numpy](https://github.com/edmBernard/pybind11_opencv_numpy).

Copy `ndarray_converter.h` and `ndarray_converter.cpp` to your project directory.

---

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())" OUTPUT_VARIABLE NUMPY_INCLUDE OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
message(STATUS "NUMPY_INCLUDE: " ${NUMPY_INCLUDE})
include_directories(${NUMPY_INCLUDE})
pybind11_add_module(mymodule "cpp2py.cpp" "ndarray_converter.cpp")
target_link_libraries(mymodule PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_compile_definitions(mymodule PRIVATE)
```

---

cpp2py.cpp

```
#include "ndarray_converter.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m)
{
    NDArrayConverter::init_numpy();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works simple and perfectly. I just lost some time because i forgot to install numpy correctly with "sudo apt-get install python-numpy" instead of only "pip install numpy".

Comment: Also, to access object attribute from python side, it is necessary to use:

.def_readwrite("frame", &MyCppObject::frame)

Comment: @Guinther CMake tries to find NumPy library which should have a C++ header, so pip install does not work. I assume you have a class `MyCppObject` which has a public member `cv::Mat frame`. Feel free to improve the post by providing a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a generic conversion of an image with any number of channels and stride possibly different from the standard one (for example if the `Mat` has been obtained as a region of interest in a bigger matrix)

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void cpp_callback1(py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{ 
    cv::Mat mat(img.shape(0), img.shape(1), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, img.shape(2)),
                const_cast<uint8_t*>(img.data()), img.strides(0));

    cv::imshow("test", mat);
}
```

- `img.shape(0)` -> rows
- `img.shape(1)` -> cols
- `img.shape(2)` -> n_channels
- `img.strides(0)` -> stride in bytes between two neighboring pixels on the same image column

Comment: Great thanks. It does not work if image.ndim == 2, in which case you have to replace `img.shape(2)` with `1` to prevent an error.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try https://github.com/pthom/cvnp

It provides automatic casts:

- Casts with shared memory between `cv::Mat`, `cv::Matx`, `cv::Vec` and `numpy.ndarray`
- Casts without shared memory for simple types, between `cv::Size`, `cv::Point`, `cv::Point3` and python `tuple`

It also provides explicit transformers between `cv::Mat`, `cv::Matx` and `numpy.ndarray` with shared memory