# Pybind11 cv::Mat from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pybind11

I want to write a function that gets an image as parameter and returns another image and bind it into python using `pybind11`.

The part on how to receive the image as parameter is nicely solve thanks [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917800/how-to-get-the-opencv-image-from-python-and-use-it-in-c-in-pybind11).

On the other hand, the returning image is a bit tricky.

Here my code (I try flipping the image using a `cv` function as an example):

```
py::array_t<uint8_t> flipcvMat(py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{
    auto rows = img.shape(0);
    auto cols = img.shape(1);
    auto channels = img.shape(2);
    std::cout << "rows: " << rows << " cols: " << cols << " channels: " << channels << std::endl;
    auto type = CV_8UC3;

    cv::Mat cvimg2(rows, cols, type, (unsigned char*)img.data());

    cv::imwrite("/source/test.png", cvimg2); // OK

    cv::Mat cvimg3(rows, cols, type);
    cv::flip(cvimg2, cvimg3, 0);

    cv::imwrite("/source/testout.png", cvimg3); // OK

    py::array_t<uint8_t> output(
                                py::buffer_info(
                                cvimg3.data,
                                sizeof(uint8_t), //itemsize
                                py::format_descriptor<uint8_t>::format(),
                                3, // ndim
                                std::vector<size_t> {rows, cols , 3}, // shape
                                std::vector<size_t> {cols * sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(uint8_t), 3} // strides
    )
    );
    return output;
}
```

And I call it from python as:

```
img = cv2.imread('/source/whatever/ubuntu-1.png')
img3= opencvtest.flipcvMat(img)
```

- My input image is an RGB image.
- Both images that are written with `cv::imwrite` are correct (the original is the same as the input and the 2nd is correctly flipped)

**The Problem is** On the python side, the returning image seems to be wrong-aligned (I can distinguish some shapes but the pixels are not in the right place.

My guess is that I have a problem while creating the `py::buffer_info`but I cannot find it. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it indeed is a problem with `py::buffer_info`, the strides to be more precise

Instead of:

`{ cols * sizeof(uint8_t), sizeof(uint8_t), 3 }`

The strides should be:

`{ sizeof(uint8_t) * cols * 3, sizeof(uint8_t) * 3, sizeof(uint8_t)}`