# C++ type from dtype (how to initialize a cv::Mat from a numpy array)

Tags: c++, numpy, opencv, pybind11

pybind11 has the following method in `numpy.h`:

```
    /// Return dtype associated with a C++ type.
    template <typename T>
    static dtype of() {
        return detail::npy_format_descriptor<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::dtype();
    }
```

How do I get the inverse? the C++ type from a variable of type `dtype` ?

**EDIT**

My original problem is that I want to bring an OpenCV image from python to c++ as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919608/11261546), note that the cast done in this answer is always of type `unsigned char*`:

```
cv::Mat img2(rows, cols, type, (unsigned char*)img.data());
```

What I want to do is to use `.dtype()` to get the "python type" and then do the right cast.

Because of this, my function signature takes an `py::array` as parameter.

```
int cpp_callback1(py::array& img)
{
//stuff
cv::Mat img2(rows, cols, type, (unsigned char*)img.data());
                                ^^^ Somehow I want this to be variable
//more stuff

}
```

Maybe I can get the `type_id` from my `dtype`?

Comment: You cannot "get the C++ type" from a runtime value. It doesn't make any sense. What does "get the C++ type" ever mean?

Comment: `decltype(var)` gives you a type of `var`.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento but what type should the requested function return ? It has to be known at compile time, and cannot depend on a run time value.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you are right, I didn't think it that deep while writting the question, I added an **EDIT** to clarify what I actually need.

Comment: @Ivan the constructor of `cv::Mat` accepts a `void*`. Why do you need to cast your data pointer to a specific type ?

Comment: @wohlstad I hadn't considered `void *` I thought it wouldn't work as they cast in the question I quoted, I'll test

Comment: It should work assuming you use this constructor: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a.

Comment: @wohlstad you are very right, thanks!! you may want to write it in detail as an answer :)

Comment: Wrote an answer (similar to my comment), so the post can be "finalized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Mat` has a [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) that accepts a `void*` for the data pointer.

Therefore you don't need to convert the `dtype` into a C++ type.
You can simply use:

```
cv::Mat img2(rows, cols, type, (void*)img.data());
```