# Converting a Python project to C++

Tags: python, c++, eclipse

I'm working on a large codebase in an Eclipse project. Our codebase has both Python and C++ code. Since I only worked in Python until now, I created the project as a Python project.

Now I'm about to work heavily with some of our C++ modules, and I would like the benefits of CTD. My Eclipse has CTD (the Eclipse C++ plugin) installed. How do I convert my existing PyDev project to work with C++?

Comment: Perhaps you should continue working with Python and to use [swig](http://www.swig.org/) to wrap C++ code in Python. I have not found any fully functional tool for wrapping code from Python to C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could add C++ nature to the project. Eclipse project could have several natures simultaneously, so you will have both python and C++ goodies.

- Right-click on the project.
- Select: New -> Other
- Under C/C++, select "Convert to a C/C++ project"