# How to convert Python to C++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to run a code written in C++ which should be the same as one I have in Python. They both use Fenics.

*My problem is that I cannot translate a Python class into a C++ class.*

For instance, my Python code is:

```
V = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "Lagrange", 1)
u = Function(V)
En = 5*dx - dot(3, u)*ds(2)

def f(self, x):
    u.vector()[:] = x
    return assemble(En)
```

*The problem here is that the compiler cannot find En as it is not defined inside the class.*

My C++ code:

```
double f(const GenericVector& x)
{
     u.vector() = x;
     return assemble(F);
}

int main()
{
   //...things that apparently work...
   Function u(Vh);
   MyClass::BilinearForm F;

}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How is it able to find `u`?

Comment: Neither `u` nor `En` are defined in the Python fragment either. Please give a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It isn't. It's another compiler error. `En` and `u` are defined in the main and I cannot pass them to the class because f is a virtual method with a fixed signature.

Comment: Declare them outside a function (outside main) and use them as `::En` and `::u`.

Comment: @RolandSmith, I edited the question. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: @NicolaFerro: Could you include your c++ code as well?

Comment: @erolyeniaras, done!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has globals in the same way Python has globals.

If you want access to something defined outside your class, either prefix it with its class name and make it static (`MyClass::Thingy`), make it a global, give it an accessor function (`MyInstance.GetThingy()`), or pass it in directly as an argument to functions that use it.

Answer (score 0):

As one of many methods, you can simply try defining F as global variable as follows:

```
...

MyClass::BilinearForm F; // The global scope

double f(const GenericVector& x)
{
     u.vector() = x;
     return assemble(F);
}

int main()
{
   //...things that apparently work...
   Function u(Vh);
   // you can use F here or call the function f
    ...

}
```

Here F is a global variable and you can use it in any method in this scope. I do not know how your class is defined or whether you are using a custom namespace but you may get rid of the scope resolution `(MyClass::)` part based on your implementation if `BilinearForm` is an accessible class here. You can also define `F` as a `static` variable so if you could provide more details, I am sure you might get more precise feedback.

Hope that helps!