# Converting this python line to C++?

Tags: python, c++, code-translation

```
diff = list(set(map(tuple, paths1)) - set(map(tuple, paths2)))
```

Where `paths1` and `paths2` are list of list of pairs.

Example:

```
paths1 = [[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(1,3),(3,5)]]
paths2 = [[(5,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(1,3),(3,5)]]
print(list(set(map(tuple, paths1)) - set(map(tuple, paths2))))
```

Should output `[((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))]`.  The inner list has to be converted to tuple first because this type of list couldn't be hashed into set.

In the provided C++ code below, I tried using the set_difference function from the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {

    std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>v1 =
        { std::make_pair (1, 2), std::make_pair (2, 3), std::make_pair (3, 4) };
    std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>v2 =
        { std::make_pair (5, 2), std::make_pair (2, 3), std::make_pair (3, 4) };
    std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>v3 =
        { std::make_pair (1, 3), std::make_pair (3, 5) };

    std::vector < std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>>V1 = { v1, v3 };
    std::vector < std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>>V2 = { v2, v3 };
    std::vector < std::vector < std::pair < int, int >>>diff;

    std::set_difference (V1.begin (), V1.end (), V2.begin (), V2.end (),
                std::inserter (diff, diff.begin ()));

    std::cout << "[";
    for (auto v : diff) {
        std::cout << "[";
        for (auto p : v)
            std::cout << "(" << p.first << "," << p.second << ")";
        std::cout << "]";
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";

}
```

This code printed `[[(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)][(1,3)(3,5)]]`.  Why is the 2nd inner list not removed when it should be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python sets are based on hashing. So, a Python set difference works by iterating the left set, looking each element up in the right set's hashmap, and skipping the ones that match.

C++ sets are based on sorting (actually, binary search trees), not hashing. The same algorithm would work, but it would take (log-linear instead of linear time. So they use a different algorithm that *does* work in linear time: assuming both ranges are sorted, you can just walk the two in parallel.

Accordingly, C++ [`set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) only works on sorted ranges:

> Copies the elements from the sorted range `[first1, last1)` which are not found in the sorted range `[first2, last2)` to the range beginning at `d_first`.

When you give it non-sorted ranges, it doesn't know you've done that, and tries to walk them in parallel, and gets confused. After the left list passes the `(5, 2)`, it's already past all the other elements, so nothing else gets skipped.