# Converting Math functions from Python to c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am attempting to convert some opencv code from python to c++, and am a little lost. The python is:

```
if 0 < R[1,1] < 1:
    # If it gets here, the pose is flipped.

    # Flip the axes. E.g., Y axis becomes [-y0, -y1, y2].
    R *= np.array([
        [ 1, -1,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  1],
        [-1,  1, -1],
    ])

    # Fixup: rotate along the plane spanned by camera's forward (Z) axis and vector to marker's position
    forward = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    tnorm = T / np.linalg.norm(T)
    axis = np.cross(tnorm, forward)
    angle = -2*math.acos(tnorm @ forward)
    R = cv2.Rodrigues(angle * axis)[0] @ R
```

So far i have:

```
cv::Mat R;
if (0 < R.at<double>(1, 1) < 1) {

            // Flip the axes.E.g., Y axis becomes[-y0, -y1, y2].
            float mult[9] = { 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1,-1, 1, -1 };

            cv::Mat FlipAxes = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, mult);

            R *= FlipAxes;

                //# Fixup: rotate along the plane spanned by camera's forward (Z) axis and vector to marker's position
            cv::Vec3d forward(0, 0, 1);
            double tnorm = tvecBest / np.linalg.norm(T)
            axis = np.cross(tnorm, forward)
            angle = -2 * math.acos(tnorm @ forward)
            R = cv2.Rodrigues(angle * axis)[0] * R


        }
```

I am lost on these lines:

```
double tnorm = tvecBest / np.linalg.norm(T)
axis = np.cross(tnorm, forward)
angle = -2 * math.acos(tnorm @ forward)
```

what is the equivalent of `np.linalg.norm` in c++ opencv?

Comment: There isn't a direct one you can use cv::sqrt() and cv::pow()

Comment: Would you be able to give me a code example please?

Comment: How about using [`norm`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm), or just directly doing [`normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize)?

Comment: Thanks, can I do this?: `cv::Vec3d tvecNorm(tvecBest);
   cv::normalize(tvecNorm, tvecNorm);`

Comment: @anti Yes, that should work.

Comment: (0 < R.at<double>(1, 1) < 1) should be ((0 < R...) && (R... < 1))

Comment: could you explain that last comment please? Do you mean loop through each element of teh Mat and check it?

Comment: (0 < R.at<double>(1, 1) < 1) result is ((0 < R.at<double>(1,1))  < 1), note extra parenthesis, I think this is not what you want.   (0 < R.at<double>(1, 1) < 1)  should be written as the && of two bools:  (0 < R.at<double>(1, 1)) && (R.at<double>(1, 1) < 1)

Comment: Also see [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the np.linalg.norm(T) is just the L2 norm :

```
sqrt(T[0]*T[0]+T[1]*T[1]+T[2]*T[2])
```

np.cross(tnorm, forward) is the cross product:

```
axis[0] = tnorm[1]*forward[2]-tnorm[2]*forward[1]
axis[1] = -tnorm[0]*forward[2]+tnorm[2]*forward[0]
axis[2] = tnorm[0]*forward[1]-tnorm[1]*forward[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! So that gives me:  `cv::Vec3d forward(0, 0, 1);
   cv::Vec3d T(tvecBest);
   cv::Vec3d tnorm = sqrt(T[0] * T[0] + T[1] * T[1] + T[2] * T[2]);
   cv::Vec3d axis;
   axis[0] = tnorm[1] * forward[2] - tnorm[2] * forward[1];
   axis[1] = -tnorm[0] * forward[2] + tnorm[2] * forward[0];
   axis[2] = tnorm[0] * forward[1] - tnorm[1] * forward[0];`

Comment: What is the c++ for : `cv::Vec3d angle = -2 * math.acos(tnorm @ forward)` ?

Comment: the @ is not a mathematical operator in python. Was it / operator ?

Comment: it is written as @, strangely. It is from here: `https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8813#issuecomment-390462446`

Comment: aha, there is actually a matlab implementation also, it looks like it should be: `cv::Vec3d angle = -2 * acos(forward*tnorm); ` However, the acos function does not like cv::Vec3d. Do I need to split it out and get three values?

Comment: from what I read they meant @ to be a dot product :
tnorm @ forward -> tnorm[0]*forward [0]+ tnorm[1]*forward [1]+ tnorm[2]*forward [2]

Comment: and angle must be a double :
double angle = -2 * acos( tnorm[0]*forward [0]+ tnorm[1]*forward [1]+ tnorm[2]*forward [2])