# Need help converting python code to c code

Tags: python, compiler-construction

Is there any compiler which will help me convert my python code to proper C code?
In my python code I am using the `xml.dom.minidom` module to parse an xml and process the results obtained by ElementsByTagName.
I don't know of any such compiler which will help me convert this kind of python code to C code.

My intention is to convert python code to a readable C code which may later be compile to an .exe file.
Cython will not be of much use to me as it is in the end writing c extensions which will later be used in python.
However, I wish to use this as a proper standalone readable C code which can later be shared with users - the c source code along with its corresponding
.py file.

My main impediment here is writing out the C code manually myself, my C skills are quite poor and it would require a more effort to sharpen my 
C skills before writing the code myself, I can not afford that luxury of time.

I was surfing and came across shedskin, but that might not just support the `xml.dom.minidom` module for my purposes

The only similar question to mine on stackoverflow:
[Is there any free Python to C translator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639195/is-there-any-free-python-to-c-translator)
does not help me out much as Cython will not help me and shedskin does not seem to support
xml.dom.minidom module.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you sure `cython --embed` won't help you?

Comment: Why does it need to be turned into C code? Why not use http://www.py2exe.org/ or similar? Or if shedskin doesn't work, how about http://kayhayen24x7.homelinux.org/blog/nuitka-a-python-compiler/?

Comment: @agf py2exe will not help me as my main aim is not generate an .exe file. My main aim is to get a readable C code which may later be used to generate .exe. I need to reword my question. Sorry about that...

Comment: In that case, @Mikko's answer is spot-on.

Comment: Funny that, half the time I *swear* that Python is just an awesome wrapper around C anyway.

Comment: Python is written in C, perhaps you can fork cpython and work your way from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Python to C translators which would produce human-readable, editable, C source code.

Comment: Also source code translations are very, very, advanced topic. I'd recommend you to learn C and rewrite it by hand. No other way. Sorry :(

Comment: Following up Mikko's remark, here is my response on translating Python to PHP, pretty much in the same vein as OP's question.

Comment: @Mikko as much as I don't want to agree with you...I know I have to agree with you, just was trying to find the easy way out. Need to get back to C now...sigh!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking in the wrong direction. Instead of looking for a generic Python to C compiler to make xml.dom.minidom more efficient, replace the library with `lxml` which is already compiled C code. The `lxml` module uses libxml2 and libxslt.

In general, you get more optomization in Python, with less work, by choosing modules that more efficient.